# Flutter Carousel, put side items behind the center card

Tags: flutter, carousel, flutter-widget, flutter-plugin

I want to know how to put the carousel items behind the center item, then when it slides there will be no spaces between items but it will stay behind

[I have this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGeLx.png)

[And I want somethig like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyTQJ.png)

This is my code:

```
CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: Sizes.width,
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
              aspectRatio: 2.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              viewportFraction: 0.8,
              onPageChanged: (index, reason) =>
                  setState(() => currentCard = index),
            ),
            items: hardcore.map((i) {
              return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        child: Image.asset(i, fit: BoxFit.cover)));
              });
            }).toList()),
```